# Control CSS UL element by Parent Div

Tags: css, parent, css-selectors

I have been trying to figure this one out, but can't seem to get it right, perhaps I'm way off with my thoughts, but this is it.

I have no control over the UL class names, they are what they are. I can only change the class name of the , the code is as below:-

```
<div class="custom-parent-div-name-changeable">
<div class="custom-child-div-name-changeable">
<div class="cant-change-this">
<ul class="name-cant-be-changed">
<li>first item</li>
<li>second item</li>
<li>third item</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem I have is the "name-cant-be-changed" class for the UL has a background and border set. I need to remove the background and border in another stylesheet, using the !important selector due to limitations in the software used to power the website.

The major setback is this same class ("name-cant-be-changed") is used twice on the page. so I need to create CSS for the "name-cant-be-changed" which is inside "cant-change-this" div class. Both instances of "name-cant-be-changed" are within a div with class "cant-change-this", but have different parent  class names, eg. "any-old-name", like so:-

```
<div class="parent-div">
<div class="any-old-name">
<div class="cant-change-this">
<ul class="name-cant-be-changed">
<li>apple</li>
<li>orange</li>
<li>banana</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I create separate CSS for the UL class "name-cant-be-changed" which is rendered based on the parent  in which both  reside?

I tried using the following, with various combinations of the class names to no avail:-

```
.custom-child-div-name-changeable > .name-cant-be-changed {
background: none !important;
border: none !important;
}
```

Can anybody shed some light on this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `>` operator means "direct child of preceding selector".  I think you want something like this:

```
.custom-child-div-name-changeable .name-cant-be-changed {
    background: none !important;
    border: none !important;
}
```

or

```
.custom-child-div-name-changeable > div .name-cant-be-changed {
    background: none !important;
    border: none !important;
}
```

or

```
.custom-child-div-name-changeable > div.cant-change-this .name-cant-be-changed {
    background: none !important;
    border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: The second option worked perfectly. I must have tried every combination possible using all of these class names except that one so thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
.any-old-name .name-cant-be-changed {…}
```

or

```
.any-old-name > .cant-change-this > .name-cant-be-changed {…}
```

The first reads: all elements with '.name-cant-be-changed' who have a parent somewhere with class `.any-old-name`.

The second reads: all elements with `.name-cant-be-changed` with an immediate parent of `.cant-change-this` that has an immediate parent of `.any-old-name`